# orientation is not working in ios 5 and it is working in ios 6

Tags: ios5, orientation

in my tabbar controller application i have many views. so i sub classed my tabbar controller like this.

```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {

   return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
  }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
  {
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }

  - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   {
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
   }

  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation            { 
// Return YES for supported orientations
//return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);


}
```

and in my view controller also

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
 }

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);

//OR return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
 }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation          {
// Return YES for supported orientations
//return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);



  }
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{

}
else
{

}
   }
```

my problem is orientation is working in ios 6 and not working in ios 5.
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this function in every tab bar page

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation          {

return YES;

}
```

//use this only if needed

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

//your view changing code

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply it is working could u plz clarify me how it works and which methods are gets called first,i was totally confused

Comment: i have one more problem, suppose i have two views for my tabbar,if i click on second one and rotate and come back to the first one all of my buttons and lables gets disturbed, is view will appear method will call when i rotate from portriat to landscape viceversa.

Comment: all tab are like subview of main view that's why shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is required in every tabbar

Comment: i don't want to call that method when i rotated is there any way?

Comment: to arrange your labels you should set there frame in viewwillappear

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32938/discussion-between-alok-and-siva)

Comment: finally, when i want to change my button position when i change the orientation which will be done in - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration, but when i came back to my original means portriat view the button postion should not change. how to proceed for this

Comment: - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)

        {
            //code for landscape mode
        }

        else

        {
            //code for portarit mode
        }
}

Comment: thnk you for ur replies and suggestions

Comment: Glad to help you! 

Happy coding

Comment: after entering into another view of tabbar controller my subviews are gets disturbed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your view controller, for ios 5

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```