# in ipad ios 5.0 version can't display app in landscape mode

Tags: ios, orientation, xcode5, uiinterfaceorientation

i make application in iphone and ipad, iphone application in Portrait (bottom home button) and i make ipad application in Landscape (right home button),in ipad ios 6,7 version display app landscape mode but ios 5 can't display in landscape

screenshot for info.plist

[image]

ios 7 screenshot

[image]

ios 5 screenshot

[image]

please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i sloved out write belove method in all ipad viewcontroller

```
    -(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this? - [orientation is not working in ios 5 and it is working in ios 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485686/orientation-is-not-working-in-ios-5-and-it-is-working-in-ios-6)

How orientation changes are handled changed between iOS 5 and 6+.